# C programming opening and reading from a file

Tags: c

```
int main(void){
     FILE *ifp;                 //input file pointer  
     int totalClock;            //total clock count
// BEGIN OPERATIONS=============================
     ifp=fopen("prog1.asy.txt", "r");
     system("PAUSE");
     assert(ifp!=NULL);
//populate the instMem with inst===================
     int i=0;
     //system("PAUSE");
     for (i=0;i<512;i++)
     {

    inst temp=parser(ifp);
    if (temp.opcode==-1)
       break;
    instMem[i]=temp;
    printf("%s\n", instMem[i].rawCode);
}
printf("\n%d instructions parsed\n", i-1);
system("PAUSE");// PAUSE TO CHECK CODE PARSING IS CORRECT========
int cont=0;
while (cont==0){
      //begin sim================================================
      //initialize the mem=======================================
      int i;
      for (i=0;i<512;i++)
          data[i]=0;
      for (i=0;i<32;i++)
          reg[i]=0;
      IF_Time=0;
      ID_Time=0;
      EX_Time=0;
      MEM_Time=0;
      WB_Time=0;
      //prompt input parameters===================================
      printf("Memory access time: c=");
      scanf("%d", &c);
      printf("\nMultiply time: m=");
      scanf("%d", &m);
      printf("\nExecute time: n=");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      assert(c>0);
      assert(m>0);
      assert(n>0);    
      //start execution now that the program has been broken to unparsed strings====
      while (0==0)
      {
            WB();
            MEM();
            if (MEM_WB.instruction.opcode==HALT)
               break;
            EX();
            ID();
            IF();
            totalClock++;
            system("PAUSE");
      }

      //PRINT RESULTS=============================================


      printf("Run again with new parameters? 0=yes");
      scanf("%d", &cont);      
     }
  fclose(ifp);  
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}

struct inst parser(FILE *ifp){

       char str[100];
       struct inst temp;
       if (fgets(str, 100, ifp)==NULL) {
          inst temp={"NULL", -1,0,0,0};
       }
       else {
       inst temp={str, 0,0,0,0};
       puts(str);
       }
       return temp;
}
```

I am trying to read in a test file so that i can parse it into strings for analysis later. It opens the test file but it doesn't read the lines of test in the code. Is there something I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your `parser` functions only reads once from the file and does nothing with the result (since `temp` would be a local variable to the `if` branch, not to the function). First thing is to remove `inst` from `inst temp = ...` to see that it reads the first instruction. Then, you need to make that function loop over all lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to format your source code on this page to make it more readable.

For parser(), I don't think you can return a structure. So please use a pointer instead. And, as Mihai mentions, "temp" is a temporary variable located on the stack, and it will be destroyed when returning from function parser().

I don't see the declarations of variables in the code snippet:

```
  IF_Time=0;
  ID_Time=0;
  EX_Time=0;
  MEM_Time=0;
  WB_Time=0;
```

So I assume you could remove some unused code to make the question clear.

The last thing is: to analyze log files, shell scripts is more suitable than C. If you're not working on a UNIX/Linux box, you could also use Perl/Python if you want. They are all less error prone and easy to debug when used to analyze log files.